# Help me evaluating integrals!

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int \cos\left(x^2\right)dx$$
I tried to evaluate the formula $\int cos(x^2)dx$ using substitution integral and integration by parts... But I couldn't

Can someone help me evaluating this integration?

Comment: This isn't an elementary integral.

Comment: Where does this intégral come from? What make you think it exist?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407575/simple-explanation-of-difference-between-cosx-and-cosx2-integrals

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks... How can I know the integral is elementary or not?

Comment: @Ivan_Raki the plethora of links in the comments should help.

Comment: @an4s Thank you sir!